# Concatenation in SQL Vertica to get year from date column?

Tags: sql, date, concatenation, vertica

I have column in SQL Vertica table like below:

```
date_col
2020-10-15
2019-09-09
2018-09-25
```

and I try to do something like this: `select TO_DATE('22-01'|| YEAR("date_col"::varchar(4)),'DD-MM-YYYY') from table`

so as to have result like:

```
2020-01-22
2019-01-22
2018-01-22
```

Nevertheless, when I try my code i have bad result like for example:

`3570-03-02` and so on...

maybe you know better solution than my code so as to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't concatenate. It's unreadable and resource intensive.

You seem to want to get the 22nd of January of the same year or the input date.

Then, use other date functions:

- `TRUNC(<date>)`  to truncate the date, to the year, in this case, to get to 1st January
- `TIMESTAMPADD()`, cast back to date, to add 22-1 days.

```
WITH
-- your input ...
indata(dt) AS (
            SELECT DATE '2020-10-15'
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2019-09-09'
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2018-09-25'
)
SELECT
  dt
, TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,22-1,TRUNC(dt,'YEAR'))::DATE AS convdt
FROM indata;
-- out      dt     |   convdt   
-- out ------------+------------
-- out  2020-10-15 | 2020-01-22
-- out  2019-09-09 | 2019-01-22
-- out  2018-09-25 | 2018-01-22
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend truncating to the first day of the year and then adding a certain number of days:

```
select date_trunc('year', date_col) + interval '21 day'
```